# downloadAsFile (google's Content Service) is not working

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use Google script's Content Service to export information from spreadsheet to XML file. The code looks like this:

```
function makeXML() {
    var StringToXML = "<tag></tag>";
    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
    output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
    output.setContent(StringToXML);
    output.downloadAsFile("f.xml");
}
```

When I launch this function - nothing happens. Though there are no errors so the function is running ok. Also when I'm trying to debug it by placing msgboxes in some lines (for example by getting content of output and messaging it) everything looks fine. Except `downloadAsFile`.

I've also tried not setting mime type (default is TEXT) but still `downloadAsFile` is not working. Tried Google Chrome, Firefox.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return the output.
Here is your modified code

```
function makeXML() {
    var StringToXML = "<tag></tag>";
    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
    output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
    output.setContent(StringToXML);
    output.downloadAsFile("f.xml");
    return output;
}
```

if you call this function in doGet or doPost depending on your method, browser will prompt you to download the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried putting `return output;` but still it doesn't work. Is it necessary to use doGet or doPost? I'm calling the function from menu (addMenu in onOpen)

Comment: Yes, It is necessary. downloadAsFile will only work when you access your application via published service URL (webapp url). And for the browser, doget and doPost are entry point. Browser will not run makeXML() function untill and unless you call it in doGet function (i.e return makeXML(); inside doGet). Alternatively, you can rename the function makeXml to doGet, and open it via wepApp url

Comment: And what's the simplest way to use this doGet? In my situation I have only a spreadsheet and just want to optimize and speed up the transfer of it's data to XML format (according to a certain algorithm). Do I need to create a button in a spreadsheet or something like that?

Comment: @user1554754 You may refer to this url to know how to deploy your app as web app https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps